# Counting the repeated text in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have to count the repeated text of a cell which is in another sheet.

Like

[image: link]

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Should the counts for `berry` and `mobile` be 2, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with SUMPRODUCT and SEARCH:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10))))
```

[image]

The main problem is that it will pick up `mobile` twice as the search requires a partial match.